# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (when hosting these files this shows only then)

Tags: header

function signin()

{

if(isset($_POST['signin']))

{

global $con;

global $db;

$name=$_POST['uname'];

$pwd=$_POST['pass'];

$name = stripcslashes($name);

$pwd = stripcslashes($pwd);

if($name!=''&& $pwd!='')

{

$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from banmoh where username='".$name."' and password='".$pwd."'") or die(mysqli_error());

$res=mysqli_fetch_row($query);

if($res)

{

session_start();

$_SESSION['uname']=$name;

$_SESSION['pass']=$pwd;

header('location:dashboard.php');

}

else

{

header('location:index.php?error');

}

}

}